# How do I install psycopg2 in Python 3.6 Windows 7

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am unable to install `psycopg2`. I am using `python 3.5.2 anaconda`

I have tried below two but getting errors.

```
pip install psycopg2

pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Error :

```
error - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2 (from versions: )
```

Comment: I am using Windows 7. Not able to install psycopg2. Please help

Comment: Have you checked https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html?

Comment: yes, I have checked it. pip install psycopg2

pip install psycopg2-binary
these two options are not working